# php IMAP connection failed

Tags: php, email, imap

I am developing a crawler to get data from email. I have 3 email addresses, which I have to use for it. On my local machine all of 3 connections with given credentials are working fine. But when I have upload to server 1 of them is working and rest of 2 are giving

```
Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate)
```

These 3 inboxes are on shared hosting and I using port `143` to read data.

In ssh I get this error:

> Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate)PHP Notice:  Unknown: Retrying CRAM-MD5 authentication after LOGIN failed. (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Notice:  Unknown: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate) (errflg=2)

Comment: maybe this will be helpfull [link to PHP manual comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php#82466)

Comment: It is likely the servers are not configured to allow plain text authentication.  Try using SSL.

Comment: It may have SSL issue, but question is should one of them should work and rest of not. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the email box type problem. That email box which not going to open was not of IMAP type. So it gives problem in openning with imap_open() function