# How do you unblock the 993 port if your firewall settings is blocking it?

Tags: php, email, ssl

I am trying to retrieve my emails from Gmail using php.
for writing the host name, this is my code:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
```

I am getting this error:

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in /home1/mtc/public_html/mtcerp/emailparser/email.php on line 10
Cannot connect to Gmail: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate)
```

I wanted to solve this by unblocking the 993 port as may be my firewall settings is blocking it.

How do i unblock this?

Comment: Have you tried going into your firewall configuration?

Comment: It looks more like an Authentication issue than a cannot connect issue. Dont you need to pass a USername and Password as well

Comment: yes a username and password is required.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not about programming but rather a system configuration problem. Try asking in SuperUser.

Comment: Firewall seems like a solution looking for a problem to solve. The problem seems to be about configuration and auth ... voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281609/php-imap-connection-failed.) which is already asked on Stackoverflow. 
Make sure that the mailbox you are trying to connect is IMAP.

PS. It doesn't look like firewall issue to me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. It is not the firewall problem or the mailbox problem. You just have to write `imap.googlemail.com` instead of `imap.gmail.com` in the hostname:

```
$hostname = '{imap.googlemail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
```